# Number patterns in Python3x

Tags: python

Im really really new to python and I found this exercise: 
You have to write a function pattern which creates the following
pattern up to the desired number of rows.
If any even number is passed as argument then the pattern should last
upto the largest odd number which is smaller than the passed even number.
Examples:

```
pattern(9):

1  
333  
55555  
7777777  
999999999  

pattern(6):  
1  
333  
55555
```

There are no spaces in the pattern
I've been trying to work on it and Im in need of help. The idea was

```
number=int(input("Insert a number"))
howmany=1
def num():
    if howmany!=number:
        howmany=howmany+2
```

And I have no idea where to go from here. Am I on the right track or not? I can code things myself, But I feel like I just need like a lead and then I can go from there myself. 
Thanks. And sorry if this is really a big facepalm moment D:

Comment: For sure you will need a loop to go from 1 to the desired number. You will just have to skip the even numbers and print the odd ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the range(input_number) and print the multiple of throwaway variable with its string representation.

```
>>> def pattern(n):
...   for i in range(1,n+1,2):
...       print (i*str(i))
...
```

Demo :

```
>>> pattern(9)
1
333
55555
7777777
999999999
>>> pattern(6)
1
333
55555
```

Comment: Also the tag used is python-3.x... You should address that too

Comment: I have no idea what to do. I'm stuck. I feel like I'm missing out on something important that gets me stuck.

    number=int(input("Input a number: "))
    for i in range(number):
        for j in range(1,i):
            print(j, end="")
        print()

Kasramvd, I tried to work with you part of the code and I couldn't figure it out D: